# Continuity and differentiability of $f(x)= x \sin(\log x^2)$

Tags: calculus

Consider the function

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
x \sin(\log  x^2), & x \neq 0\\
0, & x=0
\end{cases}
$$

Discuss its continuity and differentiability at $x=0.$

How do I plot the graph of the given function?

Comment: You don't need to plot it, although you should have an idea what it looks like. What is the effect of the $\sin(\log x^2)$ as $x\to 0$?

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  You can plot the function at [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator).  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @TedShifrin $\sin ( \log x^2) -> 0$ as $x->0$

Comment: You think so? Why?

Comment: @TedShifrin That was incorrect. $\log x^2$ would approach - infinity I suppose?

Comment: That is correct. So then what?

Comment: sin (- infinity) doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For continuity, note that
$$-|x| \le x\sin(\log x^2) \le |x|,$$
for $x \neq 0.$
Now, observe that $-|x| \to 0$ and $|x| \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ and thus, by Sandwhich Theorem, we get that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}x\sin(\log x^2) = 0 = f(0)$ and thus, $f$ is continuous at $0$.

---

For differentiability, recall that $f'(0) = \displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{f(0 + h) - f(0)}{h},$ provided that the limit exists. I will show that it does not and thus, $f$ will not be differentiable at $0$.

For $h \neq 0$, note that $\dfrac{f(0 + h) - f(0)}{h} = \sin(\log h^2)$. (Using only the definition of $f$.)
Now, note that if $h \to 0$, then $h^2 \to 0^+$ giving us that $\log h^2 \to -\infty.$ However the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to -\infty}\sin x$ does not exist and hence, we are done.

As a more formal proof, consider the sequence $x_n = \exp\left(-\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{4}\right)$. Note that $x_n \to 0.$
However, note that $\sin(\log (x_n)^2) = (-1)^n$ which clearly diverges.